# I want the latex command for the following

Tags: math-mode

[image]

Help me with code.Actually I had tried but it couldn't complie.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us in form od small complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, what you try so far.

Comment: @downvoters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, **but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.**

Comment: You should at least add a single line version of the formula, then we can help you into breaking it into lines. From the hand-writing it's difficult to guess the meaning of symbols; for instance, what's meant by “Pr”? And what's the symbol in front of “A” in the second function of the bottom line?

Answer (score 6):

Welcome! It is not necessarily the purpose of this site to convert screen shots to LaTeX code, but since this is your first question, here is something that may go in the right direction. (Note that I did not know what `Pr` is so there are two different interpretations.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\mleftright
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
 \frac{\diff}{\diff A}\left(\frac{\diff A}{\diff t}\right)+
 \frac{\diff}{\diff B}\left(\frac{\diff B}{\diff t}\right)+
 \frac{\diff}{\diff C}\left(\frac{\diff C}{\diff t}\right)\\
 =
 \frac{\diff}{\diff A}\bigl(P\,r\,(B-A)\bigr)
 +\frac{\diff}{\diff B}\bigl(r\,B-B-A\,C\bigr)
 +\frac{\diff}{\diff C}\bigl(-b\,C+A\,B\bigr)
\end{multline*}
or
\begin{multline*}
 \frac{\diff}{\diff A}\left(\frac{\diff A}{\diff t}\right)+
 \frac{\diff}{\diff B}\left(\frac{\diff B}{\diff t}\right)+
 \frac{\diff}{\diff C}\left(\frac{\diff C}{\diff t}\right)\\
 =
 \frac{\diff}{\diff A}\bigl(\Pr(B-A)\bigr)
 +\frac{\diff}{\diff B}\bigl(r\,B-B-A\,C\bigr)
 +\frac{\diff}{\diff C}\bigl(-b\,C+A\,B\bigr)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]